# We are hoping for ‘mutual divorce’ or ‘a/the mutual divorce’. Is divorce here countable or uncountable?

Tags: articles, nouns, uncountable-nouns

Is it correct to say "we are hoping for ‘mutual divorce’" or "‘a/the mutual divorce’".

Is 'divorce' here countable or uncountable?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with "uncountable nouns" - those are nouns that can be used with a determiner instead of an article, for example, "*some* water". You don't get "some divorce".

"Divorce" is a *common noun*. There are lots of divorces. You can count them.

If you were talking about a *specific* divorce, you could use the definite article, for example:

> My wife got the house in the divorce.

"The divorce" obviously means the speaker's own.

In your example, even though you are possibly alluding to your own, you are not referencing it directly. You are in fact talking about the *kind* of divorce you hope to have - a '[mutual divorce](https://www.divorce-online.co.uk/blog/what-is-a-mutual-divorce/)'. Among the many kinds of divorce you might have (for example, a messy divorce, a complicated divorce, a quick divorce) yours is but one, so the indefinite article is fine (eg "We are hoping for **a** mutual divorce").

Answer (score 0):

Divorce is 'mutual' by definition! One spouse can't be divorced and the other remain married.

When speaking of a particular couple, it's *a divorce* because it refers to the single legal decision that ends their marriage. *Divorce* is an uncountable noun when it refers to the concept of ending a marriage, or the practice as a social custom - 'Divorce is becoming more common in this country'.

Comment: What to say when one is ready for divorce and one is not?Can’t we say it a mutual divorce when one in the marriage  is hoping the other would also agree to the divorce?

Comment: You would call it a divorce by mutual consent. Obviously, if one is not ready you can't say _We are hoping_. The one who wants it would say 'I am hoping that my husband/wife will agree to a divorce'.

Comment: No you're confused. A mutual divorce is a recognised legal term. It means one that is not contested by either party. https://www.divorce-online.co.uk/blog/what-is-a-mutual-divorce/

Comment: @Astralbee: No - it's not a "recognised legal term". Your own link explicitly says: *The meaning of ‘mutual divorce’ **can be subjective**. **Some people** think it refers to a situation where husband and wife have mutually and amicably both decided they would like to end their marriage. Another meaning is [blah blah]... **But from a legal standpoint**, in the UK there is **no specific option** to apply for anything called ‘**mutual divorce**’.* My understanding of "legal term" is that it refers to some usage that has a single undisputed meaning (at least in the "legal" context).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, you're talking about the difference between 'a term in law' and terminology that the legal profession may use. I accept that it may not be a term used in a courtroom, but evidently those in the legal profession *do* use the term, to the extent that a UK legal website has a whole page dedicated to what "mutual divorce" may mean. This answer is wrong because it suggests that the OP is wrong to use the term at all, as well as being off-topic because it addresses neither of the points in the question.

Comment: @@Astralbee: I agree with what I assume Kate is saying here - *one* of the "correct" alternatives is ***a divorce by mutual consent***. Obviously there are *other* possible valid rephrasings, but ***that one alone*** is [several times more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+mutual+divorce%2Ca+divorce+by+mutual+consent&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) than ***a mutual divorce***. Just because *some* people use English very loosely doesn't mean all our answers here should encourage non-native *learners* to copy them with impunity!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree wholeheartedly, as that does not answer the question. The adjective is irrelevant, as my answer shows. It could be a messy divorce, a quickie divorce, a mutually-agreed divorce... the question was does it need an article, and yes, "divorce" needs an article in this context. Kate's example, ironically, can work without an article - "divorce by mutual consent" works just as well as "*a* divorce by mutual consent", so nothing has been learned.

Comment: @Astralbee - I answered that _divorce_ can be countable or uncountable depending on the context!

Comment: @KateBunting How is 'divorce' non-countable? Can you have *some* divorce?

Comment: @Astralbee - As I said in my answer - _He strongly disapproves of divorce. Divorce is becoming more common_.

Comment: Google Books reports dozens of hits for the article-less sequence ***application for divorce by mutual consent***, but that same string *without* an article gets just ***three*** hits. But I'm perfectly happy with both usages there, and I neither know nor care whether that implies I'm treating ***divorce by mutual consent*** OR ***mutual divorce*** as "countable nouns".

Comment: I would just add that I'm quite certain that the results returned by Google Books for what I'd call the "non-standard" usage *(**a mutual divorce**)* included significantly more "Indian English" contexts than what I got from the more "correct" phrasing ***a divorce by mutual consent***. Which isn't unexpected - even though there aren't that many actual "native Anglophones" using Indian English, it is its own "dialect", and there's no doubt it produces some useful extensions / innovations even to mainstream usage (***prepone*** comes to mind as a welcome "neologism");

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why doesn't 'application' have an article in your example? Because it's abbreviated. Also, if you had a form that said "application for divorce", are you suggesting that in that context 'divorce' is a mass noun? If you filled out the form, would you trigger every divorce in the world?